# What weapons can deal damage over time?

Tags: team-fortress-2

What TF2 weapons deal Damage over Time?  What DoT effects are in game (ie fire, etc.)?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The weapons that currently do Damage over Time are in these two lists:

- [Fire Weapons](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Fire#Weapons_which_inflict_afterburn)
- [Bleed Weapons](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Bleeding#Associated_weapons)

Which correspond to the two things that can do DoT currently, [Afterburn](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Fire) and [Bleed](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Bleeding).

The [Gloves of Running Urgently](http://wiki.teamfortress.com/wiki/Gloves_of_Running_Urgently) used to do self-damage as long as they were equipped. That's been replaced with Minicrits on yourself, but it's possible that a new item may have that effect.